# What is the significance of the .h extension in header files?

Tags: c++, c

What is the significance of the `.h` extension in header files of a C or C++ program?

Comment: "H" is for "Header" (and ["C" is for "Cookie"](https://youtu.be/Ye8mB6VsUHw)).

Comment: It's simply "h" for "**h**eader file". It's a convention and not enforced.

Answer (score 1):

No significance. It is just a convention for programmers to quickly recognize what is in the file. Standard C++ library headers don't have it.

Comment: Note that C standard library headers do have the extension.

Answer (score 1):

to mark a header file, .h stands for header as much as .cpp stands for C Plus Plus, did I get your question right?